# Parse GQL query for Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, parsing, google-cloud-datastore, gql

Besides: https://github.com/andreacimino/gql4j

Are there any other GQL parser that can generate a `Query` object from GQL String query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Engine for the Datastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075780/sql-engine-for-the-datastore)

Comment: @PeterKnego I think SQL is different than GQL